# How set a variable as a parameter value in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to set a variable as a parameter value in a Backend Listener. I tried to add the variable as

> ${"testname"}

and also as

> $["testname"]

but both options didn't work. JMeter consider them as a string and not as a variable. Any ideas how I can do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is `${variable_name_here}` so you need to change it to `${testname}` and it should start working as expected.

If there will still be problems make sure that the variable is defined and has its respective value, it can be done using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

P.S. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) instead of Beanshell (and in fact any other languages) so while your script is relatively small maybe it's a good time for migration.